# App not able to launch via branch deep link url

Tags: ios, swift, branch, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I am using branch.io SDK for deep linking in my apps. It was working fine till recently some of our iOS apps started showing very odd behaviour. The branch links(deep links) that we were creating for the user were not able to launch the application in some random devices having iOS 12 or higher versions.

I have hosted AASA file on my served(although I know branch already hosts a file for us). I have completed your troubleshooting process which was provided in Branch docs. But I am still unable to identify the issue. I have also validated my website via AASA validator.

```
    let buo = BranchUniversalObject(canonicalIdentifier: "content/123")
    buo.canonicalUrl = path
    buo.title = "some title"
    buo.contentDescription = "Some description"
    buo.imageUrl = restaurant.logo

    let blp: BranchLinkProperties = BranchLinkProperties()
    blp.feature = "sharing"
    blp.campaign = "Some random text"
    blp.stage = "new user"

    blp.addControlParam("$ios_url", withValue: path)
    blp.addControlParam(kAPIKey_BranchImageId, withValue: "\(imageId)")
    blp.addControlParam(kAPIKey_BranchStoreId, withValue: "\(restaurant.id)")
    blp.addControlParam("$desktop_url", withValue: path)
    blp.addControlParam("$android_url", withValue: path)
    blp.addControlParam("$blackberry_url", withValue: path)
    blp.addControlParam("$windows_phone_url", withValue: path)

    //Get Branch Short URL & share via UIActivityViewController
    buo.getShortUrl(with: blp) { (shortURL, _) in
        log.debug("Branch short url:\(shortURL ?? "")")
        var shareItems: [Any] = []
        if let shorturl = shortURL {
            shareItems += [shorturl]
        } else {
            shareItems += [path]
        }
    }
```

As soon as I tap on the branch url(from notes app), it opens the safari. If I long-press on that link it doesn't give an option to open in the respective app, which is used to give. And when the link is opened in safari shows me the error. Error Alert message ->  "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid". And then redirect to my respective website URL. After this when I return back to the app(manually) the data that branch link supposed to passed is received by the branch callback and everything works fine ahead. So, my main concern is why the branch link is not able to open the app.

Comment: Add the code you've tried so far.

Comment: @PGDev I have updated my question and added the code for generating the branch link.

Comment: @VaibhavSingla did you got the solution for this?